# Dead code removal for multiple bundles?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bundle, browserify, uglifyjs

Problem I'm trying to solve:

- I have multiple bundled JS files: `head.js`, `footer.js`, `some-other-page.js`
- If I had these all in a single file I could easily check for dead code and strip it
- I'd like to be able to still strip the site-wide dead code from each smaller bundle.

Willing to re-work my build to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you be more specific of what do you mean about "dead-code"? Do you mean that there is a part of a code that it is not used?

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis -- Yes.  Let's say I include jQuery and one script that just does `$('#div').hide()` -- 80% of jQuery can be stripped and various tools can remove that dead code.  Now let's say I have jQuery included in my `head.js` script and the stupid "hide" statement in the footer.  I can no longer strip the dead code.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check about dead-code is by having unit-tests to your project and then check the code coverage and see which part was never used. For more about code coverage you can see: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/monitoring-code-coverage-for-javascript.html

This will maybe need re-work of your code as well if you are not using unit-tests but it is a very good way to analyse your code for code coverage and see that some parts are never used (hence remove them from your code)

Also for code that it is not yours (e.g. for jQuery) you can use a grunt build to remove the functions/methods that you are not using. A very interesting article of how to do that is this: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/trimming-jquery-grunt . For example if you are not using the ajax from jQuery you can simply do this: `grunt custom:-ajax`. Known libraries has this functionality so you can build it on the go.

Comment: I'm not asking about my own code, I'm asking with regards to library code.  I can strip library code I'm not using, but only if it's output to a single bundle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but this doesn't at all answer my question.  As I said in my question, _I know how to do this for a single bundle_, that's not the issue.  The issue is how to remove dead code across multiple bundles.

Comment: Maybe then by using requireJS will solve that issue?? I don't have a specific solution to give you for that. Just saying... the obvious. Maybe you haven't thought about using requireJS.

Answer (score -2):

Well,

Good Idea but for understanding purpose it's good to keep it seperate but if you want to combine then use ***switch***

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say.